# Nextflow DSL2 error while constructing BLAST pipeline

Tags: dsl, nextflow, blast

```
''' #! /usr/bin/env nextflow

    nextflow.enable.dsl=2

    println "\nI want to BLAST $params.query to $params.dbDir/$params.dbName using $params.threads CPUs and output it to $params.outdir\n"
  
  
    process runBlast {

    script:
        """
        blastn  -num_threads $params.threads -db $params.dbDir/$params.dbName -query $params.query -outfmt 6 -out input.blastout
        """

    }


    params {
    query = "$PWD/input.fasta"
    dbDir = "$PWD/DB/"
    dbName = "blastDB"
    threads = 2
    outdir = "out_dir"
    }
```

What workflow {} statement should I add to the main.nf file? The basic BLAST command works, but it does not take additional parameters when added to the command line. The error I get is as follows:

ERROR ~ No such variable: query

Please help if you can, thank you!

I have been following this tutorial:
https://bioinformaticsworkbook.org/dataAnalysis/nextflow/02_creatingAworkflow.html#gsc.tab=0

And using this DSL2 documentation for support:
https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html

Answer (score 0):

Please double check that tutorial. The `params` scope is meant to be written in a separate file in your `projectDir` called `nextflow.config` not in the `main.nf`. But if you do specify parameters in `main.nf`, you need to make sure they are set before they are accessed, and I also think that it's not possible to use the `scope`. Instead write `params.query = '$PWD/input.fasta'`.

Regarding your question about the workflow: I think that you should first have a look at the concept of `Channels` instead of using the process as written in any workflow. After quickly scrolling through that tutorial, I find it very difficult to get what nextflow really is about and only throws snippets of code that don't work out of the box at the readers. Also, I find it not very helpful, that it introduces parameters very early, but not process inputs/outputs and does not mention `Channels` before section 9. Maybe you should start with the basic concept from the official docs instead? https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/basic.html